# php input file line by line make first line header one tag

Tags: php

```
    <?php

foreach (glob("POSTS/*.txt") as $filename) 
        {       

            $file = fopen($filename, 'r') or exit("Unable to open file!");
            //Output a line of the file until the end is reached


                echo date('D, M jS, Y H:i a', filemtime($filename))."<br>";
                while(!feof($file))
                  {
                  echo fgets($file). "<br>";
                  }
            echo "<hr/>";
        }
    fclose($file);



    ?>
```

so this php code reads from a folder all the files and each file line by line, i want it so that the file when being read will: for the first line add an html tag to make the first line a big heading and the next lines normal? how do i do this, thanks

Comment: you can use [fgets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) for doing that

Comment: can you show me how to implement it please into my coding

Answer (score 1):

Simply read one line before entering the loop, like this:

```
echo date('D, M jS, Y H:i a', filemtime($filename))."<br>";
echo '<h1>' . htmlspecialchars(fgets($file)) . '</h1>';
while (!feof($file)) {
    echo htmlspecialchars(fgets($file)) . '<br/>';
}
```

Note that this only works by accident in the case of an empty file, where [`fgets`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) would return false, which would be shown as `''`. You can catch that by explicitely checking for false:

```
$firstLine = fgets($file);
if ($firstLine == false) {
    echo '<h1>' . htmlspecialchars($firstLine) . '</h1>';
}
```